# Exclude getters and setters and generated members via Reflection C#

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reflection

I am iterating the methods of the class

> System.Data.Entity.DbContext

like this:

```
var methods = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Now the first method in the methods array is

> get_Database

which returns an object of type

> System.Data.Entity.Database

As you can see I only request methods with bindingflag instance and public.
If I take a look at the DbContext class in VS I cannot find a method

> get_Database

Where does it come from?

Comment: Or is it getter of the property Database?

Answer (score 0):

```
!m.IsSpecialName
```

is the important thing here.

You have to apply a filter to exclude these, I my case I also I want to exclude private members.

```
var methods = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                           BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                           BindingFlags.Instance |
                           BindingFlags.Static)
.Where(m => !m.IsSpecialName && m.IsPrivate == false).ToList();
```